# Is there a way to modify the default size of a new side note in OneNote 2010?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I am a fan of OneNote, but there is one aspect of it that makes it less useful than it could be. When I make a new side note (i.e. by clicking the OneNote icon in the system tray or pressing <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>), the size of the window of the resulting note that opens is far too large. It probably takes up 20% of my reasonably high-res screen by default. I have to click and drag to resize it, and that's a waste of my time. So, I have a two part question:

1. Is there a way of modifying some settings somewhere (perhaps in the registry?) so that the default window size of a new side note is smaller than the default? I would prefer something more in line with the size of a new "sticky" note in OS X.
2. If not, does anyone know of a fast way to shrink the size of a window using the keyboard?

I'd appreciate any advice that anyone can give. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this yet, but I thought I'd add an anecdote that makes things more interesting. So, I put in a solid-state disk as my primary drive recently. When I installed Office 2010 on this disk, I discovered that the default size of the side note is much smaller than it was on my previous drive. The screen resolution is the same as before (1600 by 1200. The default note size is now about only 5% of the screen. Perhaps somehow I had increased the default size of the side note on my previous install. Anyone care to share the default sidenote size off a fresh install for them?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like the default size of the side note either.  I resized the side note to my liking and hit "Shift+X" to close the window.  Opened a new side note the resize stayed as I wanted.
Note... Note sure if it will stay after a reboot or system cleaning, but if I only have to do it once per session, I'm fine with that.
Hope this helps.

System:
Windows 7 SP1
8GB Ram
MS Office 2010 Pro
OneNote 2010